# how to download and install hobby package for this latex scheme

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, hobby

I get  this following scheme but it doesn't work in my laptop, i work using texmaker and miKteX 2.9, i always get the error `I can't find tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex`, i enter the package manager to install it but its not found, can anyone help me to download then install it?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
\draw[thick,->] (56,-04) -- (56,04) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
\node[draw=red,dashed,thick,circle,minimum width=4cm] (n) at (56,0) {};
\fill[pattern=north east lines,opacity=.6] (58,0)arc(0:180:2cm) -- (58,0);
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,1.55) -- (58,2) node[anchor=north west] {$I^{+}(1)$};
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,-1.55) -- (58,-2) node[anchor=north west] {$I(1)$};
\draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$};
\draw (58,0) node[below right] {$1$} node{};
\draw (54,0) node[below left] {$-1$} node{};
\node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};

\begin{scope}
\clip[draw](48,1) to[closed,curve through={(50,3) .. (52,4) .. (51,6) ..(47,6) .. (46.6,5) .. (45,3.8) }] (48,1);
\node[draw,circle,fill=magenta,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
\end{scope}

\node[inner sep=1pt,fill,circle,label={below right: $x_0$}] at (50,3){};
\draw[->,shorten <= -4mm] (n1.90) -- +(0.7,0.7) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1 \cap \Omega$};
\draw[->] (51,6) -- +(0.7,0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega$};
\draw[->] (n1.300) -- +(0.7,-0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1$};
\draw[->] (n1.10) to[bend left] node[midway,below]{8*} (n.120);   %% 8* = ???
\node at (50,-1){ Some text???};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you @Claudio Fiandrino for your edit i didn't know how to do it like that using the code in the top bar of the question tools. hope you can help to download this package, or to get this drawing by another package

Comment: i download th hobby folder from CTAN and there is in it a pdf give an iformations about hobby package but i didn't know how to use it to install the hobby @Andrew

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/hobby.dtx

Comment: from the bazaar how i can use it?

Comment: The point is that you can't have hobby working with just the tikz library. You need all other files implementing the algorithm. See also [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/13304)